# Using CanCan in Ruby on Rails and want to use an 'or' condition in the can definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I have CanCan setup in RoR and it works fine when I have:

```rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new

    can :read, List, :user_id => user.id

  end
end
```

What I want to do is specify an "or" condition where either the user_id matches or else it has an access level of 'public'

```rb
can :read, List, (:user_id => user.id || :access => 'public')
```

But that of course does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a block, as [mentioned in the documentation](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks).

```
can :read, List do |l|
  l.user_id == user.id || l.access == 'public'
end
```

Answer (score 6):

For completeness, in addition to using a block, you also define multiple abilities:

```
can :read, List, user_id: user.id
can :read, List, access: 'public'
```

This is discussed on the main [Defining Abilities docs page](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities).

I'm somewhat ambivalent about which I prefer; I think the block is more communicative, because it doesn't rely on knowing that (a) abilities are `or`ed, (b) cumulative, and (c) order-dependent.

Comment: This is a better answer as blocks are not compatible with accessible_by function, whereas defining abilities this way is.